# Web Service hosted on GoDaddy fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service that works on my local machine, both through the debugger, and installed as a service on IIS.

When I install it on my GoDaddy host, this web service fails.  The logging call at the beginning of the function is not executed, and the browser receives a 400/Bad Request response.

Other services compiled together with this work as expected, so it is not a matter of the Connection String, web.config, or such.

The URL to call the service is a simple "GET" call:

```
http://tucansdev.com/TalLimoService.svc/GetTransportationOffers/1,2,1410885561,false
```

The Operation contract looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "GetTransportationOffers/{pickupLocID},{dropoffLocID},{pickupTime},{isAsInstructed}")]
List<GetTransportationOffersResult> GetTransportationOffers(string pickupLocID, string dropoffLocID, string pickupTime, string isAsInstructed);
```

The log on the GoDaddy server confirms the fact that the call was received, but nothing more.

Just to be thorough, here is my service model from web.config:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TalLimoService.TalLimoService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <!--Service Endpoints-->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above-->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TalLimoService.ITalLimoService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Worse yet, it used to work.  I changed the third parameter from an explicit date to time ticks, which doesn't affect the interface as far as I can tell. When I revert to the old version, I still get the 400 response, so I guess it isn't the code as such.  What is it?

**NEXT STEP**

Since it used to work, I simplified the code to a completely trivial interface, which then had no problems.  I then restored all the parameters to the endpoint, but with an empty function.
The first two lines of the function look like this:

```
   List<GetTransportationOffersResult> transList = new List<GetTransportationOffersResult>();
   TalLimoDataDataContext tlData = new TalLimoDataDataContext();
```

When the function has only the first line, everything is fine. The second line causes the service to return Error 400.  I would then say that there is something wrong with my .dbml file, but other functions in this web service make the same call, and there is no problem!

Comment: have you contacted the service provider to see if something on their hosting domain has changed.. what if there is something wrong with your basicHttpsBinding can this be debugged locally to replicate or reproduce..?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in the web.config file after all. On my machine I had:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataSourceConnectionString"...
```

and on the server, for some reason, it was

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TalLimoConnectionString"...
```

So on my machine it worked, and on the server it didn't. I guess the moral of the story is never assume anything.